# Mocking services with spring boot and Spock

Tags: spring-boot, spock

I have a service that uses another service, which I want to mock out.

```
@Service
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PatientRepository patientRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MyHelper myHelper;

    public Office createOfficeAccount(Office commonOffice) throws Exception {

      // this line calls another service via http, I want to mock it:
      Account newAccount = myHelper.createAccount(officeAccount);
      return customerRepository.save(customer);
}
```

Here is my test class:

```
class KillBillCustomerServiceTest extends BaseSpecification {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService = Mock(CustomerService)

    @Autowired
    private PatientRepository patientRepository = Mock(PatientRepository)

    @Autowired
    private MyHelper kbHelper = Mock(MyHelper)

    def setup() {
        customerService.setPatientRepository(patientRepository)
        customerService.setMyHelper(kbHelper)
    }

    def "create new Account from Common Office"() {

        def commonOffice = createOfficeForTests()
        CustomerService customerService = new CustomerService (myHelper: kbHelper)

        when:
        kbHelper.createAccount(commonOffice) >> new Account() // want to mock it, but it is still calling the actual class to try and make the network call 
}
```

My question is how do I mock my MyHelper class so that it doesn't actually try to make the real call, but instead just returns a stub object?

Comment: that is for Mockito and I don't think its anything different than what I am doing above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you can't specify expectations in the when block and this is the root cause here.

Check the [Spock interaction testing tutorial](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html). It has a section called "Where to Declare Interactions", and it states that you can declare expectations in "setup" (given) or "then" blocks only.

Here is a simplified example of such an interaction that works on my machine:

```
interface Account {}

class SampleAccount implements Account {}


interface DependentService {
   Account createAccount(int someParam)
}

class DependentServiceImpl implements DependentService {

    Account createAccount(int someParam) {
       new SampleAccount()
    }
}


class MyService {

    private DependentService service

    public MyService(DependentService dependentService) {
        this.service = dependentService
}

public Account testMe(int someParam) {
    service.createAccount(someParam)
}

}
```

Here you can see some service (MyService) to be tested and it depends on DependantService interface (I worked with interface because I don't have CGLIB in a classpath of my sample project, it doesn't really matter for the sake of your question).

And here is a test in spock:

```
class SampleSpec extends Specification {

 def "check"() {
    setup:
    def mockDependentService = Mock(DependentService)
    def mockAccount          = Mock(Account)
    1 * mockDependentService.createAccount(5) >> mockAccount
    MyService testedObject  = new MyService(mockDependentService)
    when:
    def expectedAccount = testedObject.testMe(5)
    then:
    expectedAccount == mockAccount
  }
}
```

As you see, I've got my expectations set in given block here.

Comment: Perfect answer, that got me over the hump so I can now mock one of the @Autowired classes to return a stubbed out object for testing.  Thank you for the great help!